# Add option to attribute in database table

Tags: attributes, database, attribute-options

In database where can I find a table where I could add another option to admin attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I have to say that directly editing the database is not recommended; and if you do modify the database, you should do a backup first.

First, find the ID of the attribute you want to modify:
(in this example, I use 'color')

```
SELECT * FROM eav_attribute WHERE attribute_code = 'color';
```

There, I see the `attribute_id` is `92`.

Then you need to add a row to `eav_attribute_option`. Set the `attribute_id` with the id you got from the previous select.

Get `option_id` from your new row, and add it to `eav_attribute_option_value` with `option_id` as `option_id`, and set `value`

Comment: You mentioned that editing databse is not the best option. What would be the "right" thing to do? I would like to add an option to availabitly attribute.

Comment: For what you're doing there might not be a better way. I suppose the "right" way would be to write a module to add the option, which would programmatically add that value to the database.